# annotations not working with jetty stand alone server with servlet

Tags: annotations, jetty

I am trying to create a simple example of a jetty standalone web server using a servlet and annotations.  If i use xml to map the URL to methods it works, but when I try to use @WebServlet() the jetty server does not successfully map the request to the method.  Does anyone know what I might be missing?  I have researched online for examples but do not see anything missing.  Thank you.

My servlet is this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet3
*/
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorldServlet3 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloWorldServlet3() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at:  ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

The web.xml file is:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
```

and the linux command line to launch the server is :

java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar

---

As a side note:

If i use the following xml it works - but I dont need to use annotations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>test_jetty</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>helloWorldServlet3</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.xyz.www.HelloWorldServlet3</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>helloWorldServlet3</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am developing this in Eclipse and exporting as a WAR file which is then dropped into the jetty standalone /webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jetty Distribution 9.3.x, add the following to your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

```
--module=annotations
```

> **DO NOT** make changes in your `${jetty.home}`.  Don't edit, delete, rename, move, touch, symlink, or anything else in your `${jetty.home}` directory.  Leave that directory alone.  Use the `${jetty.base}` properly and you'll have an easier to maintain instance configuration, as well as brain dead easy Jetty upgrades.

Comment: thank you addding --module=annotations solved the issue

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70872360/80772.