# use @WebServlet annotation in maven jetty plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, jetty

I build an web application in my ecplise with maven plugin
I want debug it in jetty.

this is my code:

```
@WebServlet(name="Startup",value="/", urlPatterns = {}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class Startup extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("start up");
        QCloud.setupSDK();
    }
```

this is  pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M2</version>

            <configuration>
                <stopPort>8889</stopPort>
                <useTestClasspath>false</useTestClasspath>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

when i start the jetty server. no error shows. and i can see the index page.
but i can't visti my servlet. It seems the servlet haven't init with jetty server.
then I build a war and put it in the webapps of a tomcat server.
everything is ok ,the servlet init successfully, anyone knows why?

Comment: Do not use images of code. Please post your actual code.

Comment: If I delete the ,value="/" in the annotation. It does not work fine.

Comment: Don't use unstable releases of Jetty.  `9.3.0.M2` is milestone/alpha/beta release.  Use a stable release version, such as `9.4.6.v20170531`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's your case but I faced similar issue with Jetty.

When using annotations the **web.xml** file is not needed anymore, so if you have it then remove it (even if there are no servlets mapped inside) and it will make the trick.

Also note that either ***value*** or ***urlPatterns*** are required attributes for **@WebServlet** annotation but you shouldn't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This Github issue mentions that servlet API moved packages from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. Only Jetty 11 and later changed to reading annotations from `jakarta`.  Perhaps, your code uses the newer jakarta servlet API and older Jetty 9.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/5964#issuecomment-777083559